# Fetch all tokens (ERC20, ERC721, ERC1155) owned by a specified address

Tags: erc-20, json-rpc, erc-721, erc-1155

I am building an app and I need to fetch all tokens (ERC20, ERC721, ERC1155) owned by a specified address. I've seen some services for fetching ERC20 (ETHplorer) or ERC721 (Etherscan, OpenSea) tokens owned by a user with a specified address, but found nothing that would fetch ERC1155 tokens owned by an address nor a service that would fetch all these tokens at once.

I've seen that there are some `multicall` libraries, that allows you to check a balance of tokens in a single batch, so the amount of RPC calls get reduced. Also I've found the token address lists for ERC20 and ERC721, but not for ERC1155.

Do you have any idea, how could I achieve this? Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: You need to use a solution like [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/).

Comment: Which subgraph would provide data like that?

Answer (score -1):

ERC1155 are not as popular as ERC721 so there is less smart contract to look into it I think. For the call it's pretty mush the same thing than ERC721.